# How to use property as a variable?

Tags: java, properties

For example I have property:  `project.password.time=123456`

Then I want to use it in some class as a variable.

For example, `Long time = {my property}`

This doesn't work: (java.lang.NumberFormatException: null)

```
Long time = Long.valueOf(System.getProperty("project.password.time"))
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify "i have property..."

Comment: did you try something like _System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version" ));_ to test if your properties are actually loaded??

Comment: Also note that there should be no `"`s in the property definition, i.e. correct form for property in a property file is `project.password.time=123456`

Comment: @VirajNalawade other properties work

Comment: @JiriTouse sorry, i have it in properties file without " already)

Comment: SHow us how you load the properties file

Comment: Please show us an executable, minimal example of your problem - the properties file content (if in property file and not commandline), java code and how you run it.

Comment: 5 comments asking for some more information for this very unclear question. How the heck did it get 3 upvotes?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose had the same question... but probably should be asked on meta .. :)

Comment: @VirajNalawade how to load it? I `can`t add more information because i really have no idea what else i have to do before calling System.getProperty

Comment: I think you need to add how you're setting the properties. The most probably is that you're not loading the properties on System.properties

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file lets say config.properties then you can

```
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    final String propertyFileName = "config.properties";
    final InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        props.load(inputStream);
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Property file not found " + propertyFileName);
    }
    System.out.println(props.getProperty("project.password.time"));
```

system println will print the value 123456

As i am not sure what is your demand this seems to be easiest answer.
As Jiri noticed, you want to put your properties propertyName=value in the file as the property file act like a map.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

    Long time = Long.valueOf(env.getProperty("project.password.time"));
```